# What are the prerequisites for unicode uppercasing to work in .NET6?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, .net-5, .net-6.0

The code

```
"ჾ".ToUpper()
```

should return `"Ჾ"` in .NET 5. This is in fact what does happen in [this jsfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RLi2Bf).

However, when I try to make this work, in .NET6 Preview 3 on Linux, it does not work. Instead, I get:

```
"ჾ"
```

So clearly, something is wrong, but I do not know enough .NET to know where to start looking. So I figure if I know what the dependencies are, which are required for ToUpper to work properly, I could start looking there.

So, what are the dependencies/configuration/libraries/etc, required for the proper operation of `String.ToUpper()` on Unicode strings?

Comment: Does it work correctly in your Linux environment if you compile against .NET5 instead of 6?

Comment: No, I was using .NET5 before I switched to .NET6, and string casing didn't work then either.

Comment: It works in .net 6 on Mac.

Comment: Try [passing a CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=net-5.0#System_String_ToUpper_System_Globalization_CultureInfo_). Maybe there is a issue with your Culture on Linux.

Comment: @magnetron In jsfiddle, it seems to work fine with the Invariant CultureInfo https://dotnetfiddle.net/6z3vhZ

Comment: Confirmed that it works fine on Linux in .NET6 preview 3 using microsoft's containers: `docker run -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.100-preview.3`

Comment: @j... I was using .NET6 preview 3 in my devcontainer, which used portions copied from the MS devcontainer: https://github.com/darklang/dark/blob/main/Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing here seems to be libicu - it didn't work with libicu60, and works with libicu66.